# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in

Tags: shipping-methods, fatal-error

I have this issue in my `Magento 1.9.0.1`, when I try to go into Shipping methods I'm getting this message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

Are there any of you can help me solve this error?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any third party shipping extension? Try disabling them one by one and check if error is gone.

Comment: For debugging try to print the group fields or elements after line no 267. It will stop printing just before it gives a fatal error. So you will have the idea which field is creating the issue which leads you to particular extension or code..